# readmore.js put "readmore" link inside div not below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created annotations which may or may not be long, so I want to use readmore.js plugin.
As my annotation may be also empty, I have to set min height of div to be sure that all has same size (it is line of 4 objects)

```
<annotation>
  <div style="width:100%;min-height:70px;overflow:hidden;">
    <p><%= p.annotation %></p>
  </div>
</annotation>
```

This is readmore.js part

```
<script>
$('annotation').readmore({
  speed: 75,
  collapsedHeight: 60,
  moreLink: '<a href="#">Ukáž viac</a>',
  lessLink: '<a href="#">Schovaj</a>'
});
</script>
```

My issue is when I have longer annotation, Read more text is put below the annotation tag, not inside, so everything below this div is moved by one line

[image]

Is there any way how to put "read more" link inside div/annotation so it will not move anything below?

UPDATE: after first answer I found out I need a fixed height block for text and put inside read more only if necessary, thanks

UPDATE2:
ok found a solution for my problem, but it is workaround

```
 <% if p.annotation.length < 90 %>
                            <div style="height:11px"></div>
                            <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put the "read more" link inside the annotation tag, you can just use that :

**(Note that the "read more" link are wrapped in span tag with class="lnk")**

**Javascript :**

```
$('annotation div').readmore({
  speed: 75,
  collapsedHeight: 70, // same as min-height in div tag
  moreLink: '<span class="lnk"><a href="#">Ukáž viac</a></span>',
  lessLink: '<span class="lnk"><a href="#">Schovaj</a></span>'
});
```

**CSS :**

```
annotation {
  position: relative;
}

.lnk {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Now all annotations have the same height (70px in the example)

http://codepen.io/Aywac/pen/yeWqvd

Comment: thanks, now it is inside, but when I remove min-height from div, it moves all other projects with short annotations 
I am looking for a way how to have fixed size of block of text (even there is no text) and have "read more" just for those which are longer...without moving objects below
is it possible?

Comment: Do you tried to give the div tag a min-height:70px; for example and in script add collapsedHeight: 80 or more ? the collapsedHeight value should be higher than min-height value.

Comment: yes when I was playing with these values, one result was that "read more" was not shown or read more was shown to each annotation, even it was not necessary and read more just shows more empty place

Comment: I created an example here : [http://codepen.io/Aywac/pen/yeWqvd](http://codepen.io/Aywac/pen/yeWqvd). I see no problem using a collapsedHeight value higher than the min-height value of div.

Comment: thanks, but as you can see first annotation has smaller height than other two and this will break my design, because I have annotation in project block and there is stuff below...all is bordered in one object and these objects need to be exactly same in height...so when one annotation has smaller block, it is all moved
I hope I wrote it understandably